# Перегрузка оператора + для класса односвязный список

Tags: c++, visual-c++

По заданию: оператор должен возвращать адрес головы нового списка, содержащего элементы обоих списков для которых вызывался оператор.

```
const List<T>& operator+ (const List<T>&obj)
    {
        List<T> newList; //Создаю новый список
        ListItem<T> *temp = head; //Временная переменная, хранящая в себе элемент списка. Начинаем с головы.
        uint i = 0;
        while (i++ < count) //В новый список заносим элементы
        {
            newList.AddHead(temp->item);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp = obj.head;
        i = 0;
        while (i++ < obj.count)
        {
            newList.AddHead(temp->item);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        return *newList; //Возвращаю указатель новый созданный список.
    }
```

При запуске - ошибка компиляции. error C2100: недопустимое косвенное обращение
В чем может быть ошибка? Спасибо.

return *newList; - на этой строке ошибка.

```
//Структура элемента
    template<class T>
    struct ListItem
    {
        T item; //значение
        ListItem *next; //указатель на след. эл
    };

//класс список
    template<class T>
    class List
    {
    private:
        ListItem<T> *head; //указатель на первый элемент списка
        uint count; //кол-во элементов
    ......
```

Comment: Ну хотя бы сказали, в какой строке, или привели описание классов... А так - гадание на кофейной гуще, право слово...

Comment: Добавил информацию.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, у вас

```
List<T> newList;
```

Что такое `*newList`, которое вы пытаетесь вернуть под видом `const List<T>&`? Оператор разыменования `*` применим к *указателям*, но не к объектам.

Вряд ли вы переопределяли его для своего `List<T>`.

Только если вы возвратите просто `return newList;`, то тем самым впадете в другую ересь :) - возвращать ссылку на локальный объект, уничтожаемый при выходе из функции...